# Raw and html_safe not working with Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-safe

I'm using first time gem "bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails". Before i was on ckeditor and both of these tags working fine with ckeditor. But not this case with bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails.

```
   See screenshot of my form
```

[image: screenshot from 2013-07-03 03 17 05]

Also see results with "raw". You can clearly see that html tags are still visible.

[image: screenshot from 2013-07-03 03 19 16]

Any help??

Thanks

Comment: I think its better if you post the code instead a screenshoot.